# strange behavior with system command in c++

Tags: c++, cluster-computing, system, wine

I have written a code in that at some point calls an external executable using the system command.
Here is how I do this:

First remove the output files of the external code.

```
boost::filesystem::remove("Results/CVground.bin");
boost::filesystem::remove("Results/CVground.BUD");
```

then write input files for the external code. The code is too long to paste here. It just writes few ascii files.

Then run the model. To make things even worse as you can see I'm calling a windows executable under linux using wine.

```
std::string sim_command = "/opt/wine-stable/bin/wine ";
sim_command.append(cvd.simulationExe()).append(" CVsimAqua.in >/dev/null");
int sys = system(sim_command.c_str());
```

Essentially the command I'm calling under system is the following

```
int sys = system("/opt/wine-stable/bin/wine Simulation3.02.exe CVsimAqua.in >/dev/null");
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on the suggestion I modified the above command so that it prints to a file as such

```
int sys = system("/opt/wine-stable/bin/wine Simulation3.02.exe CVsimAqua.in > log.dat");
```

This is usually takes a couple of minutes to complete.
Then I'm doing a check that the output files actually exists as follows:

```
if (!boost::filesystem::exists("Results/CVground.bin")) {
    std::cout << "\t\tSys output from rank " << rank << " is " << sys << std::endl;
    fun.clear();
    fun.push_back(10000000);
    fun.push_back(10000000);
    boost::filesystem::current_path(main_dir);
    return;
}
```

I have found that in some cases I do get the following print in my log file. The rank number is different in each run.

```
 Sys output from rank 78 is 32512
```

What I don't understand is that the output of system is positive, which I believe it means that the system command was successful. Is there any way to capture more information from the system command?

**UPDATE**

After I changed the from /dev/null to log.dat I realized that when the system fails it doesn't even create the log.dat file, however I always check with `system(NULL)` that system is available before calling the system.

I have found extremely difficult to debug this because these errors occur only when I run the code on the cluster.

Is it possible that the system command returns before the execution code finishes? I have seen a definite NO answer to that question but I was wondering if things are getting trickier since I'm calling via wine.

Thank you

Comment: Is it a type "processor number" ? if you mean process number ie. PID then there is no problem with that, each time you run a new process you will get a new PID, Linux does increment the PID each time a new process is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The `system` function returns the exit code from the command you run. By convention, processes return 0 on success and non-zero on failure. What a non-zero exit code means, depends on the application, `wine` in this case. If may be easier to debug if you don't redirect its output to `/dev/null`

There are some specific return values for when the `system` call itself fails: `-1` is a process could not be created, and 127 if a shell could not be executed. See `man 3 system` for the details on those cases.